# Joining multiple tables in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I'm not that good at mySQL. 
What I'm trying to do here is join 2 tables: 
`1. users`
`2. comments`
I'm trying to make a comment system where it should pull the username and profile picture from `users` table and the comments and date_posted from the `comments` table.

Here is my query:

```
$mem_query = mysql_query("SELECT `comments`.`comment_id` AS `comments_id`, `users`.`user_id` AS `users_id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`profile_pic`,`comments`.`txt_content`,`comments`.`date_posted` FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `comments`.`user_id` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = '$post_id'");
```

And I want to run the query using the while loop:

```
while($run_mem = mysql_fetch_array($mem_query)){
    $comment_id = $run_mem['comments_id'];
    $txt_content = $run_mem['comments.txt_content'];
    $profile_pic = $run_mem['users.profile_pic'];

?>
    //Run all the comments depending upon the post_id.
<?php
        }
?>
```

As of now, it is giving me this error: - THIS IS NOT SHOWING AFTER my 2nd update.

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\simpleblog\view.php on line 73
```

How do I fix it? Thanks.

P.S: I know 'mysql_query' is being deprecated in PHP. I'll change that later.
P.S 2: I fixed the query from `table.column` to `table`.`column`, however, its not showing any errors but its not pulling any information from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the ` symbols, they should look like:

```
`table`.`column`
```

and not:

```
`table.column`
```

Comment: Thanks, its not showing errors anymore but its not pulling any information from the tables. I updated my post, please check the codes again

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem...There was an error in my syntax. I fixed it after testing my code in phpMyAdmin. What you pointed out was one of the major flaw in my code. So thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

there is a big syntax error in your query:

```
SELECT `comments.comment_id` AS `comments_id`, `users.user_id` AS `users_id`, `users.username`,`users.profile_pic`,`comments.txt_content`,`comments.date_posted` FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users.user_id` = `comments.user_id` WHERE `comments.post_id` = '$post_id'
```

should be

```
SELECT `comments`.`comment_id` AS `comments_id`, `users`.`user_id` AS `users_id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`profile_pic`,`comments`.`txt_content`,`comments`.`date_posted` FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `comments`.`user_id` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = '$post_id'
```

you wrote this: `comments.user_id` but it has to be this: `comments`.`user_id` and that at almost every position where you did that wrong

Comment: Thanks, its not showing errors anymore but its not pulling any information from the tables. I updated my post, please check the codes again

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

Looks like the latter happened. An error occurred and the mysql_query call returned false.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PolishPrince the question is way bigger than it needs to be, and focussed on the wrong parts of the code. This answer cuts it in half. Time for a new question, what is the syntax error in the statement. Or the error in the connection string.